# Inconsistency with re.findall method

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm using regex to extract some pattern, however there seem to be `findall` method returns different results for same string and pattern at different times.

At first, it doesn't find any match object and returns empty list, then when I build the pattern object one group at a time (pattern object consist of three groups) and apply `findall` method at every time it returns true results.

And at the last step (which I would have same pattern as with the starting one) it returns expected results even though it is same pattern object as with the one it returned empty list

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, can someone address this mighty issue

I'm not well experienced with asking questions here on SO, if there is an unclear part please point out

```
In[98]: a[1]           # a string object from list "a"
Out[98]: 'c48: 1777'

In[99]: a_re= re.compile('r(c[0-9]+)(: )(.*)') # pattern object

In[100]: a_re.findall(a[1])
Out[100]: []

In[101]: a_re= re.compile(r'(c[0-9]+)')

Out[102]: a_re.findall(a[1])
Out[102]: ['c48']

In[103]: a_re= re.compile(r'(c[0-9]+)(: )')

In[104]: a_re.findall(a[1])
Out[104]: [('c48', ': ')]

In[105]: a_re= re.compile(r'(c[0-9]+)(: )(.*)') 

In[106]: a_re.findall(a[1])
Out[106]: [('c48', ': ', '1777')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a minor typo, if you can even call it that. Put the `r` outside of the string like so:

```
a_re= re.compile(r'(c[0-9]+)(: )(.*)')
```

Comment: thank you, I just realize it now. This is funny, I feel ashamed :)

Answer (score 0):

**code:**

```
import re

print(re.findall(r'(c[0-9]+)(: )(.*)','c48: 1777'))
```

**output:**

```
[('c48', ': ', '1777')]
```

Which reach the same result.